# Do I have to match arguments/parameters when making override function?

Tags: actionscript, overriding, subclass

if I want to add something to the implementation of

```
public static function createPopUp(parent:DisplayObject,
                                   className:Class,
                                   modal:Boolean = false,
                                   childList:String = null,
                                   moduleFactory:IFlexModuleFactory = null):IFlexDisplayObject
{   
    return impl.createPopUp(parent, className, modal, childList, moduleFactory);
}
```

do I have to put all the arguments in my function declaration or does it pick them up implicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - ActionScript doesn't support method overloading only overriding, in which case your method's signature must exactly match that of the overridden method.

But you are trying to override a static method which is not possible in ActionScript at all. If you want something like in the code snippet create your class not inheriting anything, put a static createPopUp method inside and let it call static createPopUp method from the class you want to decorate and call your class'es static method instead of the original one.

This impossibility to sensible inherit (or inherit at all) static methods is one of the reasons why one should try to restrain from using statics as much as possible - statics take away the power of inheritance from OO languages.

Comment: for some reason now that i have it hooked up... it's not letting me override it.. it as in it says the functions aren't override functions even though they're named identically to the class i'm inheriting from. is this related to the fact that PopUpManager is a singleton maybe?

Comment: ActionScript has no means to stop you inheriting singletons, you cannot make constructors private. That said it can prevent you from creating you inherited class by using a private, external not visible class, as a parameter to the constructor. But wait - this is a static method! You cannot override static methods in ActionScript! I'll edit the answer...